# linear regression analysis

Tags: regression

i am given data for  analysis following data:relationship between  height and weight,question is :is relationship between them  linear?like
$y$=$a$+$b$*$x$+$e$
where e is error,or quadratic?or cubic?data  is following(y denoted height, x-weight)

```
y   x
170 65
167 55
189 85
175 70
166 55
174 55
169 69
170 58
184 74
161 56
170 75
182 68
167 51
187 85
178 62
173 60
172 68
178 55
175 65
176 70
```

i have calculated a and b and get following result

```
y=139.6155237+0.5308912572*x
```

i dont know how to calculate e?or what me result means?please help me how to find e and how to check correctness of my work

```
EDITED:
i have edited my work,i am sure it is correct,what  now should i do?
```

Comment: Is this only part of your data?

Comment: not but others are like  gender,age and BMI

Comment: Yes, coefficients are correct now. What is your task? To estimate the model and find residuals?

Comment: yes exactly,i have put x variable but have not got exact y value,so is it not linear yes?

Comment: That is fine, your model can't be perfect. The difference that you get is residual (-4.12 first data point, -1.81 second etc.). Again, try to plot your data. It is hard to tell whether the relationship is linear, there are too few observations, but linear model, in my opinion, is the best choice here.

Comment: ok i will try to do it and in case of any questions,i will post here

Answer (score 1):

First you fit the data with your expectation model: $y=a+bx$

Then you compute pertuberations of data points around the model curve (line). Analysis of this will give you variance in data points (the error). The least squares approach expects the errors are distributed normally, so that the errors should be samples drawn from gaussian distribution.

Your (least squares) estimator have two properties: precision and accuracy. I think the precision is what you want to compute. Accuracy is about bias, and this is harder to grasp (e.g. all weights are slighly bigger because of uncalibrated measurement device).